# Generate sequence column for unique rows in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which looks like below:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
 R      a      abc
 R      a      abc
 G      b      def
 G      b      def
 G      b      def
```

and I want to add new column to it which will generate the index for these unique rows as per the count like below:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | new_column
 R      a      abc      0
 R      a      abc      1
 G      b      def      0
 G      b      def      1
 G      b      def      2
```

Please help me to generate this new column using pyspark.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partition the data by column and then use the row number to assign values to new column.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

windowSpec = W.partitionBy("col1","col2","col3").orderBy("col1","col2","col3")
df.withColumn("new_column", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)).show()
```

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: Can you suggest a SQL solution if you know a one, without `window`, as with it the solutions are usually slower?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Not sure about sql. We can translare it to a query `spark.sql("""SELECT * , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3  ORDER BY col1,col2,col2) new_column FROM data_df""")` but I think it would again translate into same execution plan.